# Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext in UWP APP fails after reset

Tags: c#, windows, sharepoint, uwp, sharepoint-online

I am trying to connect to a SharePointOnline 2013.

In my C# Console Application everything works fine, but if I try (nearly) the same code in an Universal App, **it is not possible to create multiple instances of a ClientContext nor setting the credentials multiple times**.

Im using the Microsoft.SharepointOnline.CSOM Version: 16.1.4727.1204 (released on 11.12.2015)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UseContextMultipleTime();
        UseContextMultipleTime();
    }

    public static void UseContextMultipleTime()
    {
        using (var context = new ClientContext("https://something.sharepoint.com"))
        {
            var securePassword = new SecureString();

            foreach (char c in "password".ToCharArray()) securePassword.AppendChar(c);

            context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("username", securePassword);

            try
            {
                context.ExecuteQuery();
                string status = "OK";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string test = ex.ToString();
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Below the Universal App version, which crashes in the second method call:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        UseContextMultipleTime();
        UseContextMultipleTime();
    }

    public void UseContextMultipleTime()
    {
        using (var context = new ClientContext("https://something.sharepoint.com"))
        {
            context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("username", "password");
            try
            {
                context.ExecuteQueryAsync().Wait();
                string status = "OK";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string test = ex.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I set the credentials only once, it will work.

Does anybody know a solution for this problem? I will appreciate every kind of hints.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? It seems to be an ongoing issue with SharePoint Online Credentials + UWP. Thoughts?

Comment: @Codesmith No, I didn't. There is a problem with using SP Online Credentials with UWP, e.g. you can't define the credentials a second time if you once logged in successfully. 
I found also some other issues with the Microsoft.SharepointOnline.CSOM -> Timeout of the ClientContext after 1 hour

Comment: Would it make sense to cache the `SharePointOnlineCredentials` object -- so that each time you needed a new context, you just gave it to same creds object?

Comment: Guess not -- Looks like all you can do only ever create one context, and then restart your app when it expires.  (I've read that if it's the default app, you can just have it exit itself, and then the OS should restart it.  I have not confirmed this yet.)

Comment: @Tipura Does SharePointOnlineCredentials takes string(password) as argument? I guess it takes SecureString as argument and it's not there in UWP.

Comment: @mahemadhi sorry for the delay. No, SharePointOnlineCredentials doesn't take SecureString as argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was solved in the latest CSOM update. Everything works fine now.